# What if multiple players have the same hand via using all the shared cards?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

I'm trying to learn the basics of poker, and I encountered this bit of info:

> Sometimes the best texas hold em hand is made by the five shared cards on their own. If they were 10-10-10-10-A and you had 9-9 your hole cards would not play as there is a four-of-a-kind of higher value already showing.

I am unclear about this. What if every player chooses `10-10-10-10` as their hand, since they're shared cards? Who wins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a split pot if cards are revealed at show down.

In Texas Hold 'Em players make the best 5 card they can from the 7 they have available.  When those best 5 are the 5 community cards this is known as 'Playing the board'.  If multiple players best hand is 'the board' and this is the winning hand then it is a split.  the 2 cards they have in there hand take no part in determine the winner.

eg. two players hole cards are AA and 23.  The board comes out 6789T.  Both players have a Ten High Straight and nothing more so split if cards shown at showdown.

Comment: Personally I'd give the pot to the 23 for having the stones to make it to showdown with that hand. =) Or maybe to AA as compensation for getting absolutely coolered...